# How to insert value in data base using SQLite extend class in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm trying to make a cart to study the SQLite database. When I insert data into my database by calling function `addProduct()`, my app closes. I don't know why the app is closing, I think the problem is in my function `addProduct()`.I am calling this function from a fragment. Any help would be appreciated!

```
   import android.content.ContentValues;
   import android.content.Context;
   import android.database.Cursor;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
   
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;
   
   import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
   
   //database functions class
   public class db_helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   
       private static final String product_name = "product_name";
       private static final String id = "id";
       private static final String price = "price";
       private static final String count = "count";
       private static final String total = "total";
       private static final String img = "img";
       private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
       private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "user";
       private static final String TABLE_ = "cart";
   
   
       public db_helper(@Nullable Context context) {
           super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   
       }
   
       // Creating Tables
       @Override
       public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
           String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ + "("
                   + id + " TEXT," + product_name + " TEXT,"
                   + price + " TEXT," +count + " INTEGER," +total + " TEXT," + img + " TEXT" +")";
           db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
   
       }
       // Upgrading database
       @Override
       public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
           // Drop older table if existed
           db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_);
   
           // Create tables again
           onCreate(db);
       }
   
       // code to add the new contact
   
       public void addProduct(cartmodal modal) {
         SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
   
           ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
           values.put(id, modal.getId());
           values.put(product_name, modal.getProduct_name());
           values.put(count, modal.getCount());
           values.put(total, modal.getTotal());
           values.put(price, modal.getPrice());
           values.put(img, modal.getImg());
   
           // Inserting Row
           db.insert(TABLE_, null, values);
           //2nd argument is String containing nullColumnHack
           db.close(); // Closing database connection
       }
   
       public List<cartmodal> getAlldata() {
           SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
           List<cartmodal> List = new ArrayList<cartmodal>();
           // Select All Query
           String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_;
   
   //      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
           Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
   
           // looping through all rows and adding to list
           if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
               do {
                   cartmodal modal = new cartmodal();
                   modal.setId(cursor.getString(0));
                   modal.setProduct_name(cursor.getString(1));
                   modal.setPrice(cursor.getString(2));
                   modal.setCount(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
                   modal.setTotal(cursor.getString(4));
                   modal.setImg(cursor.getString(5));
                   // Adding contact to list
                   List.add(modal);
               } while (cursor.moveToNext());
           }
   
           // return contact list
           return List;
       }
   
   
       public void updateCount(cartmodal modal) {
           SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   
           ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
           values.put(id, modal.getId());
           values.put(product_name, modal.getProduct_name());
           values.put(count, modal.getCount());
           values.put(total, modal.getTotal());
           values.put(price, modal.getPrice());
           values.put(img, modal.getImg());
   
           // updating row
            db.update(TABLE_, values, id + " = ?",
                   new String[] { String.valueOf(modal.getId()) });
       }
   
       public void deleteproduct(String id_){
           SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
           db.delete(TABLE_,id+" =?",new String[]{id_});
   
       }
   }
```

**Error Log**

```
    V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
    D/ViewRootImpl@d62e4b3[Home]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
    D/ViewRootImpl@d62e4b3[Home]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
    D/ViewRootImpl@d62e4b3[Home]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
    D/ViewRootImpl@d62e4b3[Home]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
    D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.firstprinciple.white, PID: 17749
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:445)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:391)
            at com.firstprinciple.white.database_sql.db_helper.addProduct(db_helper.java:55)
            at com.firstprinciple.white.ui.home.HomeFragment$12$4.onClick(HomeFragment.java:622)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7870)
            at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14970)
            at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7839)
            at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29363)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
    I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17749 SIG: 9
```

The above is the `error stacktrace` and I can't seem to resolve this issue.

Comment: show some log, there is exception for shure in there which help debug this problem

Comment: hello sir,l am updated log details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exchange this line

```
public db_helper(@Nullable Context context)
```

to this

```
public db_helper(@NotNull Context context)
```

and pass proper `Context` to it. `Context` just can't be null for `SQLiteDatabase`

Comment: am passing like this 'db_helper db_helpe=new db_helper(getContext());'

Comment: where do you call this? seems like `getContext()` returns `null` for you

Comment: try to exchange `getContext()` to `getContext().getApplicationContext()` - app context is more appriopate for sqlite helper instance, but in your case it will throw immediately `NullPointerException`. inspect your code and obtain proper non-null `Context` or initiate sqlite helper at the moment when `Context` will be available

Comment: sir i need to call this function in a fragment then plizz expline how to call this class

Comment: then show your `Fragment`s code, at which moment you are calling `db_helper` constructor and how do you add your fragment to `Activity`

Comment: you may try to put this line: `db_helper db_helpe=new db_helper(getContext());` in `onResume` method (in `Fragment`). at this moment `Context` will be available for shure, in `onCreate` it won't be. check out [Fragment lifecycle diagram](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) and call all context-related methods after attaching `Activity` (`onActivityCreated` call)